# How to skip nested functions in python testing

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

```
def calculator(a, b):
      sum = a + b
      minus = a - b
      calculate(a, b)
      return sum, minus

def test_cal():
      sum, minus = calculator(5, 4)
      assert sum == 9
      assert minus == 1
```

My requirement is when above test is called calculator method then how can we skip calculate (nested method in calculator)??

I heard we can achieve it through mock and patching, could you please help me here?

Comment: Why would you want to skip it? If you're not testing your entire function then you really haven't tested it at all.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow ! You're question is not really clear, maybe you should reformulate it. If you don't want calculate to be execute, you just have to comment it, while testing, which is the simpler way.

Comment: If you google `mock function python` you will find information to get you started.

Comment: https://changhsinlee.com/pytest-mock/

Answer (score 1):

You can create simple "mokey-patch" function `patch_calculate()` that temporarily patches `calculate` method to do nothing:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

def calculate(a, b):
    print("I don't want to call this")

def calculator(a, b):
      sum = a + b
      minus = a - b
      calculate(a, b)
      return sum, minus

@contextmanager
def patch_calculate():
    global calculate
    try:
        original_calculate = calculate
        calculate = lambda *args: None  # do nothing inside calculate
        yield
    finally:
        calculate = original_calculate

def test_cal():
    with patch_calculate():
        sum, minus = calculator(5, 4)
    assert sum == 9
    assert minus == 1

test_cal()
```